# How to choose between two if statements based on If VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write some code that says if a cell's value = yes then run this "IF" code, if not then run a different "IF" code.

Here is my sub :

```
Sub LTATradesTest()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim LastRow As Long, fs As Worksheet, ds As Worksheet, x As Long
Dim ltaLR As Long
Dim cmntText As String

With ThisWorkbook
    Set fs = .Worksheets("Filters")
    Set ds = .Worksheets("Data")
End With

LastRow = ds.Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

ClearSelections
SortData
RemoveComments
DeleteConditionalFormat
UnmergeAllCells

For x = 4 To LastRow

   If fs.Range("F2") = "Yes" Then GoTo Line1 Else GoTo Line2

Line1:        If ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And ds.Cells(x, 40) >= _
        fs.Range("C2") And ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") Then Goto Line3

Line2:       If ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") Then

Line3:     With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")

            ltaLR = .Cells.Find("*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1

            .Cells(ltaLR, "B").Value = ds.Cells(x, 3) 'League
            .Cells(ltaLR, "B").Resize(2, 1).Merge
            .Cells(ltaLR, "C").Value = ds.Cells(x, 4) 'Home Team
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "C").Value = ds.Cells(x, 5) 'Away Team
            .Cells(ltaLR, "D").Value = ds.Cells(x, 81) 'Home Pos
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "D").Value = ds.Cells(x, 91) 'Away Pos
            .Cells(ltaLR, "E").Value = ds.Cells(x, 82) 'Home H/A Pos
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "E").Value = ds.Cells(x, 92) 'Away H/A Pos
            .Cells(ltaLR, "F").Value = ds.Cells(x, 83) 'Home H/A FH Pos
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "F").Value = ds.Cells(x, 93) 'Away H/A FH Pos
            .Cells(ltaLR, "G").Value = ds.Cells(x, 84) 'Home H/A SH Pos
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "G").Value = ds.Cells(x, 94) 'Away H/A SH Pos
            .Cells(ltaLR, "H").Value = ds.Cells(x, 85) 'Home Att
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "H").Value = ds.Cells(x, 95) 'Away Att
            .Cells(ltaLR, "I").Value = ds.Cells(x, 86) 'Home Def
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "I").Value = ds.Cells(x, 96) 'Away Def
            .Cells(ltaLR, "J").Value = ds.Cells(x, 88) 'Home H/A Form
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "J").Value = ds.Cells(x, 98) 'Away H/A Form

            'Home Scored
            .Cells(ltaLR, "K").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 57).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "K")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "K").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "K").AddComment Text:=ds.Cells(x, 57).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value

             'Away Scored
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "K").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 71).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "% (" _
                & ds.Cells(x, 71).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR + 1, "K")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "K").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "K").AddComment Text:=ds.Cells(x, 71).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value

             'Home Conceded
            .Cells(ltaLR, "L").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 58).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 40).Value) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "L")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "L").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "L").AddComment Text:=ds.Cells(x, 58).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 40).Value & ")"

            'Away Conceded
            .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "L").Value = Round((ds.Cells(x, 72).Value _
                / ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR + 1, "L")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "L").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR + 1, "L").AddComment Text:=ds.Cells(x, 72).Value & "/" & ds.Cells(x, 41).Value & ")"

            'Combined HT 0-0
            .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 229).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "M")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").AddComment Text:=(ds.Cells(x, 229).Value + ds.Cells(x, 243).Value) & "/" _
                        & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Resize(2, 1).Merge

            'Combined FT 0-0
            .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 257).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "M")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").AddComment Text:=(ds.Cells(x, 257).Value + ds.Cells(x, 275).Value) & "/" _
                        & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Resize(2, 1).Merge

             'Combined O1.5
            .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + _
                ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "M")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").AddComment Text:=(ds.Cells(x, 54).Value + ds.Cells(x, 68).Value) & "/" _
                        & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Resize(2, 1).Merge

             'Combined O2.5
            .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 55).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "M")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").AddComment Text:=(ds.Cells(x, 55).Value + ds.Cells(x, 69).Value) & "/" _
                        & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Resize(2, 1).Merge

             'Combined O3.5
            .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 56).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "M")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").AddComment Text:=(ds.Cells(x, 56).Value + ds.Cells(x, 70).Value) & "/" _
                        & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Resize(2, 1).Merge

            'Combined BTS
            .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 59).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "M")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").AddComment Text:=(ds.Cells(x, 59).Value + ds.Cells(x, 73).Value) & "/" _
                        & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Resize(2, 1).Merge

            'Combined GP 1-0
            .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 144).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "M")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").AddComment Text:=(ds.Cells(x, 144).Value + ds.Cells(x, 159).Value) & "/" _
                        & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Resize(2, 1).Merge

             'Combined GP 0-1
            .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Value = Round(((ds.Cells(x, 147).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) / (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value _
                + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value)) * 100, 0) & "%"
                        If HasComment(.Cells(ltaLR, "M")) Then
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Comment.Delete
                        End If
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").AddComment Text:=(ds.Cells(x, 147).Value + ds.Cells(x, 162).Value) & "/" _
                        & (ds.Cells(x, 40).Value + ds.Cells(x, 41).Value) & ")"
                        .Cells(ltaLR, "M").Resize(2, 1).Merge
        End With
     End If

Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The only difference between the two IF statements that i want to choose from is this line of code:

```
If ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1")
```

I have tried using IF GOTO THEN ELSE but this does not work. Can anyone point out where i am going wrong?

Comment: There is no need for the GOTO you can have nested IFs which are more readable and better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to process the same code depending upon either of two conditions. The conditions could be stacked into a single If statement with multiple And/Or operators but for clarity, I will assign them to two boolean variables.

```
dim b1 as boolean, b2 as boolean

...

For x = 4 To LastRow

   b1 = cbool(ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And _
              ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
              ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2"))
   b2 = cbool(ds.Cells(x, 40) >= fs.Range("C2") And _
              ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2"))

   If (fs.Range("F2") = "Yes" and b1) Or (fs.Range("F2") <> "Yes" and b2) Then

      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")

   ' rest of code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you're making so complicated things? You can't simply do:

```
If fs.Range("F2") = "Yes" Then
    If ds.Cells(x, 1) = ds.Range("E1") And ds.Cells(x, 40) >= _
    fs.Range("C2") And ds.Cells(x, 41) >= fs.Range("C2") Then 
        "Here line 3 code"

Else 

End If
```

Comment: Surely by doing this i would have to copy the Line3 code twice.... It is what i am trying to avoid

Comment: Line 2 doesn't go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Erm...  Nest the "IF" statements?

```
If [A1]="Yes" Then
    If First_condition = SomeValue Then
        'Do Stuff
    End If
Else
    If Second_condition = DifferentValue Then
        'Do other Stuff
    End If
End If
```

If you need to, then the Stuff that you Do can be to set a Boolean variable (`True`/`False`) for later usage:

```
Dim BoolTest AS Boolean

If [A1]="Yes" Then
    BoolTest = (First_condition = SomeValue)
Else
    BoolTest = (Second_condition = DifferentValue)
End If

If BoolTest Then
    'Do Stuff
End If
```

Comment: explaination of the code above: In this case the first condition will decide which branch of the if you will go to: if the condition 1 is not met you will directly go to the outer else branch (same as your goto line2) in case it is true it will use the normal if branch (line1) after having gone down either of these branches it will go on using the normal path (line3)